# Tomcat is web server or application server?

Tags: web-server, application

please let me know !!

Comment: I recommend the removal of this entry. IMHO, it is a junk question.

Answer (score 4):

[Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is an open source servlet container that provides a "pure Java" HTTP web server environment for Java code to run

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on where you draw the line in definition. It's not a general purpose web server, though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is a Webserver and a Servlet Container.
   Manytimes it is confused as application server. but it is definitely not an fullfledged Java EE application server